# How to connect to SQL Server using oledbConnection

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to connect to SQL Server with OledbConnection but its showing error

> *Server does not exist or access denied*

My code is

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
{
   try
   {
      // test the connection with an open attempt
      conn.Open();
      this.Dispose();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      // inform the user if the connection was not saved
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Connection Test");
   }
}
```

Comment: You use OleDbConnection in a right way. The problem is in your connection string. Also I don't understend, why do you call this.Dispose()?

Comment: Please show the example of your connection string (remove passwords as necessary)

Comment: Take a look at : http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here are list of available **[connection string for MSSQL Server](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005)**. Much better if you use **[System.Date.SqlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx)** namespace.

```
Using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
         connection.Open()
         // do something here
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
         connection.Close()
    } 
}
```